# Four “spinless” noninteracting fermions are conﬁned in a one-dimensional harmonic potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, fermions

Four “spinless” noninteracting fermions are conﬁned in a one-dimensional harmonic potential.

The energy eigenvectors of the system $|\phi_n\rangle$ correspond to the energy eigenvalues $$E_n = \hbar \omega(n + \frac{1}{2})$$ where $$n = 0,1,2....$$

I want to calculate the ground state energy of the system, and determine the ground state of the system in terms of the energy eigenvectors $|\phi_n\rangle$.

So I have that

$V(x)=\frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 x^2 $

In (spinless) fermionic system, Pauli exclusion prohibits multiple occupancy of single-particle states.

I have only ever worked in a $2$ particle system

If they are fermions, antisymmetrize $|u\rangle $

$$\hat A|u_i\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1 : \phi;2 : \xi \rangle −|1 : \xi ;2 : \phi \rangle$$

If someone can help me with this question I'd really appreciate it.

**Edit**

Would Space-antisymmetric function be zero if particles are identical
$4$ particles:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{24}}(|1\rangle|2\rangle|3\rangle|4\rangle+|4\rangle|1\rangle|2\rangle|3\rangle+|3\rangle|1\rangle|2\rangle|4\rangle+|2\rangle|1\rangle|3\rangle|4\rangle-|2\rangle|1\rangle|4\rangle|3\rangle-|3\rangle|1\rangle|4\rangle|2\rangle-|4\rangle|1\rangle|3\rangle|2\rangle-|1\rangle|2\rangle|4\rangle|3\rangle$$

Answer (score 2):

The antisymmetrized ground state is:
$$|\psi_0\rangle = \frac 1 {\sqrt{24}}[+|0\rangle|1\rangle|2\rangle|3\rangle-|0\rangle|1\rangle|3\rangle|2\rangle-|0\rangle|2\rangle|1\rangle|3\rangle+|0\rangle|2\rangle|3\rangle|1\rangle+|0\rangle|3\rangle|1\rangle|2\rangle-|0\rangle|3\rangle|2\rangle|1\rangle-|1\rangle|0\rangle|2\rangle|3\rangle+|1\rangle|0\rangle|3\rangle|2\rangle+|1\rangle|2\rangle|0\rangle|3\rangle-|1\rangle|2\rangle|3\rangle|0\rangle-|1\rangle|3\rangle|0\rangle|2\rangle+|1\rangle|3\rangle|2\rangle|0\rangle+|2\rangle|0\rangle|1\rangle|3\rangle-|2\rangle|0\rangle|3\rangle|1\rangle-|2\rangle|1\rangle|0\rangle|3\rangle+|2\rangle|1\rangle|3\rangle|0\rangle+|2\rangle|3\rangle|0\rangle|1\rangle-|2\rangle|3\rangle|1\rangle|0\rangle-|3\rangle|0\rangle|1\rangle|2\rangle+|3\rangle|0\rangle|2\rangle|1\rangle+|3\rangle|1\rangle|0\rangle|2\rangle-|3\rangle|1\rangle|2\rangle|0\rangle-|3\rangle|2\rangle|0\rangle|1\rangle+|3\rangle|2\rangle|1\rangle|0\rangle]$$

so you need to find:

$$ \langle \psi_0|E|\psi_0\rangle $$

Note that the state:

$$ |ijkl\rangle $$

has the 1st fermion in $i^{th}$ state with energy $E_i$, the 2nd fermion in $j^{th}$ state with energy $E_j$, and so on.

Moreover, it is an eigenstate of energy:

$$ \hat E |ijkl\rangle = (E_i+E_j+E_k+E_l)|ijkl\rangle $$

So you have 576 inner products to calculate, but
states satisfy the orthogonality condition:

$$\langle i'j'k'l'  |ijkl\rangle =\delta_{i'i}\delta_{j'j}\delta_{k'k}\delta_{l'l} $$

which should reduce it to 24; however, you should be able to do it with only 1.

Comment: Can that simply become $E\langle \psi_0|\psi_0\rangle$ So for $n=0$ in the ground state we would have $\frac{1}{24}*\frac{\hbar \omega}{2}$

Comment: Opps. I should start from 0.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Does this hold if the fermions had a spin $\frac{1}{2}$ value or does the energy values change?

Comment: This is a great QM problem b/c it falls under Feynman's edict: "shut up and calculate"...meaning, I have zero intuition into what or why, just apply QM as we know it. If spin is available, each $N$ can hold 2 particles instead of 1. If you want the ground state, then it's a product of spatial and spin wave functions, and the ground state is the antisymmetric product with the lowest energy.

Comment: The fermions cannot all go into the 1-particle ground state because of the Pauli exclusion principle. There are two states available at $ n = 0$, due to the spin degree of freedom. The third and forth electron has to go into a state at $n = 1$. Hence $E_{0,4F} = 4\hbar\omega$ .

Answer (score 0):

why not construct the antisymmetrization of four objects? as an example, for three it would be like $|1,2,3 \rangle_{a} = |1\rangle |2\rangle |3 \rangle + |3\rangle |1\rangle |2 \rangle + |2\rangle |3\rangle |1 \rangle - |2\rangle |1\rangle |3 \rangle -|3\rangle |2\rangle |1 \rangle - |1\rangle |3\rangle |2 \rangle$ with an appropriate normalization... for four it would just be the next step.

Comment: Ok, once constructed what does that show? Could you explain how that relates to finding the energy of the ground state